# Right click do left click then right click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an AngularJS application, and for some reason when I right click on anything it does left click first then right click. For example,  if I click with the right button on an anchor it goes to the link then shows the right click options list.

Any idea why this could happen?

Comment: what do you mean by **right click do left click**?

Comment: probably you didn't prevent the default event to fire

Comment: @PankajParkar I mean it act like you click left mouse button first then you click right mouse button

Comment: @slash197 for which event ?